# Is there a way to order by COUNT('column') without returning an integer?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to make this query work correctly in Drupal 8. I want to return the events in order of most frequently occurring in the database table (Users vote for the event they prefer). But I only want to display the event name and not the number of times someone has voted. Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT `event`
    FROM     `eventform`
    GROUP BY `event`
    ORDER BY COUNT(`event`) DESC
```

In SQL pro it returns correctly the following data.

1. Brewery
2. Conference
3. Concert
4. Dinner
5. Musical

With Drupal, I am getting the following data.

1. Brewery
2. 10
3. Conference
4. 8
5. Concert
6. 7
7. Dinner
8. 6
9. Musical
10. 4

How can I make the following code return only the event names?

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('eventform', 'm');
$query->fields('m', ['event']);
// It doesn't return the correct order unless I use
$query->addExpression('COUNT(event)', 'count');
$query->groupBy('event');
// I want something like orderBy(COUNT('event'),'DESC'), but this
// returns incorrect ranking;
$query->orderBy('count','DESC');
$votes = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Here is how I'm rendering:

```
 $rankings=array();
  foreach($votes as $key){
    foreach ($key as $value) {
      $rankings[] = $value;
    }
  }

    $build = [
      'rankings' => [
        'rankings_child_element' => [
          '#theme' => 'item_list',
          '#list_type' => 'ol',
          '#items' => $rankings,
        ]
      ],
      '#empty' => t('No votes found'),
    ];
    return $build;
```

}
}

Comment: Could you also post the code that renders the result? Your query can get a column that is then not output by the code that renders it. An easy fix is in the output code rather than the query.

Comment: Similar to what @greggles said, if you use `fetchCol()` instead of `fetchAll()` you'll just get an array with values from the `event` column

Comment: thank you guys! fetchCol() worked!! and tweaked the foreach. works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $sth = $connection->select('eventform', 'm');
  $sth->addField('m', 'event');
  $sth->addExpression('COUNT(m.event)', 'count');
  $sth->groupBy('m.event');
  $sth->orderBy('count','DESC');
  //- Execute the statement
  $data = $sth->execute();
  //- Get all the results
  $results = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

you will get the `$results` as an array something like:

```
array:5 [▼
   0 => array:2 [▼
     "event" => "Brewery"
     "count" => "10"
   ]
   1 => array:2 [▼
     "event" => "Conference"
     "count" => "8"
   ]
   2 => array:2 [▼
     "event" => "Concert"
     "count" => "7"
   ]
   3 => array:2 [▼
     "event" => "Dinner"
     "count" => "6"
   ]
   4 => array:2 [▼
     "event" => "Musical"
     "count" => "4"
   ]
 ]
```

if you want to get only the `event name` loop thought the `$results` something like :

```
 $events_name = [];
 foreach ($results as $result){
    $events_name[] = $result['event'];
  }
```